# clicking on compiler warnings doesn't take me to the source code in XCode

Tags: xcode

I used to be taken to the line in the source code when I clicked on a warning in XCode 8.2.1.  Now I just see this display which tells me the file containing the problem but not which line is causing the issue.  Is there some setting I've mistakenly changed to cause this behavior?  I had recently defined a new scheme for using XCode to run Python however that scheme should be totally separate from the scheme being used to run this iOS app.  Is there some known scheme issue where there are spillover interactions or something?

[image: Displayed instead of source code]

[image: after clicking]

Answer (score 1):

Click the icon as shown in the below picture - [image]

Comment: That simply expands the view on that same page showing a bunch of text but not taking me to the source code nor giving any indication of the line in the source causing the issue.  I will add a screen shot of that into the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top level warning `Swift compiler warning` It should show the warning line.

The warning indicates that you are trying to handle a String, but don't specify type, so you could potentially end up with nil. Specify a `?? ""` to handle the warning.